# Vue solo me renderiza un solo componente

Tags: vue.js, symfony

El problema que tengo es con las Rutas. Cada vez que accedo a una ruta, esta me devuelve el mismo componente. El que ponga en:

```
render: h => h(App),
```

Mi app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './components/App';

import router from './router/';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
/**
 * Create a fresh Vue Application instance
 */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
});
```

Mi router, index.js:

```
import Router from 'vue-router'

import events from '../components/Events'
import event from '../components/Event'
import vuelogin from '../components/LogIn'

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/vuelogin',
      name: 'vuelogin',
      component: vuelogin
    },
    {
      path: '/events',
      name: 'events',
      component: events
    },
    {
      path: '/events/:eventId',
      name: 'event-detail',
      component: event
    }
  ]
})
```

Mi controlador VueController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class VueController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/vuelogin", name="vue_login", options={"expose"=true}, defaults={"param" = "vuelogin"})
     * @Route("/event/{id}", name="event", options={"expose"=true}, defaults={"param" = "event"})
     * @Route("/events", name="events", options={"expose"=true}, defaults={"param" = "events"})
     *
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        return $this->render('base.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'VueController',
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Los componentes que importo son para testear

Esta linea parece lo primordial para renderizar cualquier componente.

```
render: h => h(App),
```

Espero vuestra ayuda.

Gracias.

Edit:

El problema lo he solucionado cambiando el app.js a esto:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './components/App';
import Event from './components/Event';

import router from './router/';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
/**
 * Create a fresh Vue Application instance
 */
new Vue({
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Gracias por el aviso.

Comment: Nos puedes enseñar los componentes y que extension tienen?

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente tengas que declarar los componentes que no estas viendo en el objeto components de la instanciación de Vue que tienes en app.js.

Te quedaria asi

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './components/App';
import events from './components/Events'
import event from './components/Event'
import vuelogin from './components/LogIn'

import router from './router/';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
/**
 * Create a fresh Vue Application instance
 */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App, vuelogin, events, event }
});
```

Yo uso Vue.js transpilado con typescript y ya el propio IDE me va avisando de estos jaleos que suelen ser un lio. Recomiendo hacer el wrapper con typescript, al principio es lioso pero luego merece la pena